# Unit testing order of printing to standard output

Tags: ruby, rspec, io

In RSpec, I would like to test whether the program prints the correct messages to standard output in the right order.  I'm using "puts" to print.  The output is supposed to be

```
A
B
C
```

How would I do this?  I tried

```
messages = ['A', 'B', 'C']
messages.each do |message|
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(puts).with(message).once
end
```

but the test still passed when I switched the order of the messages.  The test shouldn't pass when the messages are being printed in the wrong order.

How would I write the RSpec correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using RSpec 3, you can use [ordered](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/message-order)

```
messages = ['A', 'B', 'C']
messages.each do |message|
  expect(STDOUT).to receive(puts).with(message).ordered
end
```